# Error al cargar archivos javascript

Tags: python, django

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación la cual he puesto DEBUG en falso para poder usar mis vistas personalizadas sobre el error 403, 404 y 500, pero estoy teniendo un problema y es que en el navegador no se me cargan mis archivos *JavaScript*.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi archivo settings:

```
import os

from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'tzep%r^slcn(w&=%w#@h7#k5xo^43g)=&7pu$6#@-$dj1ui-g='

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'users',
    'tasks',
    'projects',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wrike.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'wrike.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-co'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Bogota'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Y este es mi código base.html:

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Wrike</title>
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/halfmoon@1.1.1/css/halfmoon-variables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ddd46d4aa2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>
</head>

<body data-set-preferred-mode-onload="true">
    <div class="page-wrapper with-navbar with-sidebar with-navbar-fixed-bottom">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            {% include 'navbar.html' %}
            {% include 'sidenav.html' %}
        {% endif %}
        
        
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                {% include 'messages.html' %}
                {% block content %}
                {% endblock %}
            </div>
        </div>

        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
            {% include 'footer.html' %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/halfmoon@1.1.1/js/halfmoon.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.formset.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    {% block script %}
    {% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

Todo funcionaba bien hasta que puse el modo debug es false para poder probar las vistas personalizadas sobre los errores, ahora estuve mirando distintas soluciones como poner `type="application/javascript"`, `type="application/json"`, pero nada me ha funcionado.

Comment: Sin ver cómo tienes esos scripts en tu html, o cómo los llamas, es poco o nada lo que podemos hacer, salvo decirte que leas [ask] y [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: ya edite mi pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre una solucion la cual esta en https://stackoverflow.com/a/64455396/12293663
basicamente solo hay que hacer lo siguiente:

```
import mimetypes

mimetypes.add_type('text/javascript', '.js', True)
```